# How to check a defined enum type variable in a class was assigned to or not?

Tags: c++, enums

I want to check if a variable in a class was set or not? How can I do it?

```
enum Color {
   red,
   blue
};
class example {
   Color c;
   void set_color(Color c) { this->c = c; }
   Color get_color() { return c; }
   bool check_color_is_set() {
       if (c == Color) {} // compile error
       if (c == NULL) {} // compile error
       return true;
   }
```

I want to know if the variable `Color c` was assigned or not ?

Comment: It's not possible. Unlike some other languages uninitialized variables will have an *indeterminate* value (that will seem almost random), and using them, even just to check their value, leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Classes in C++ don't have a 'null' or 'not assigned' value.

Comment: You should define an `unkown` alternative in your enum and set it as default value for `c`

Comment: Your `c` cannot be null because it's a value type and those cannot be null.

Comment: If you want to make sure that `c` always have a valid value, then you need to initialize `c` in a constructor.

Comment: the correct solution would be to set the variable in the constructor, then you dont need the check ;). Btw your example is either a not so good example or instead of the class you should rather use the plain enum.

Comment: i sense a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), if your class had a proper constructor your problem would not exists, so what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: if you really need what you're asking for (and I'm not convinced), then have a look at a construct like [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: to make the point even more clear: the purpose of classes is **not** to write getters and setters, and if you need to call a setter to bring your object into a valid state, then you did something wrong. If on the other hand "no_color" is a valid state then you should either use an `std::optional` or add a `no_color` to the enum

Comment: Nitpick: Each of `set_color`, `get_color` and `check_color_is_set` are just as (in)accessible as the data member `c`. I would discard them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than having a value for not assigned (as in [@code707's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604113/1294207)) you can do a few things.

### Same approach, user can use the class uninitialized - mitigation

All are based on storing a bool if the user calls set correctly.

Use your get/set encapsulation to check if it has been set:

```
class example {
private:
    Color color;
    bool isColourSet = false;

public:
    Color get_color() const;

    void set_color(Color newCol) {
       color = newCol;
       isColourSet = true;
    }
...
```

Then you can use this bool in various ways depending on your desire:

---

**Throw an exception**

```
    Color get_color() const {
       if (!isColourSet) throw some_exception; // It wasnt Set!! Throw
       return color;
    }
```

This way, you don't have an extra enumeration element, and you protect against dishing out an undefined value by throwing an exception.

---

**Returning an error code**

If you don't want to throw an exception, you could pass a return argument and return an error:

```
ErrInt get_colour(Colour &out) const {
    if (!isColourSet) return STANDARD_ERROR_VAL;
    out = color;
    return STANDARD_SUCCESS_VALUE;
}
```

This is quite similar to the concept of a *Bad Value* in the enumeration.

---

**Use `std::optional`**

Since `c++17` you also have a new way `std::optional`, where you can optionaly return (instead of throwing an exception or returning an error value).

```
class example {
public:
    std::optional<Color> get_colour() {
        return color;
    }
    void set_color(Color newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }
private:
    std::optional<Color> color;
}
```

Then the user could use it as such:

```
auto myColor = myExample.get_colour();
if (myColour) { // Here you can check the optional
    myColour.get() // Do something with colour.
...
```

### New approach, user cannot set the class in a bad state - redesign

As opposed to setting a value and having to check if it has been set correctly, perhaps you can design the class such that it can *never* be in an invalid state. Lets walk through how we might do this:

**1 Type Safety**

We don't want a user to be able to set a random value for color that we dont know about. In the current implementation `enum` will be a type that can be set with likely any `int` value! What does it mean when someone does `set_color(538)`? We can fix this with c++11 `enum class`:

```
enum class Color {
    RED,
    BLUE
}

// This now causes a compiler error:
set_color(523);
// You can only use it like this:
set_color(Color::Red);
```

**2 Constructor Arguments**

We can force the user to choose the initial colour by providing only a constructor that requires a color:

```
class example {
public:
    example(Color startColor) : color(startColor) {}        
...
private:
    Color c;
}
```

This means that a user will be unable to create the class without it having an initial color. Now we can add our set function in case the user wants to change the color:

```
void change_color(Color newColor) {
    color = newColor;
}
```

**3 Conclusion**

Now you have a class where the user can never get themselves into a situation where it is invalid. I believe this is much better then trying to detect if the user has stuffed up creating the class.

Comment: You could mention `std::optional`.

Comment: @YSC true, i am still catching up with fun c++17 stuff.

Comment: Note though with the power of `std::optional`, I'd keep as member variable an optional rather than a couple color+bool.

Comment: @YSC true, but my other answer is a better solution anyway. I will update this one as well.

Answer (score 4):

What about having special value for "not assigned" ?

```
enum Color {
   nocolor,
   red,
   blue
};
class example {
   Color c = nocolor;
   void set_color(Color c) { this->c = c; }
   Color get_color() { return c; }
   bool check_color_is_set() {
       if (c == nocolor) {} 

       return true;
   }
```

Comment: a null (starting) value paradigm!

Comment: you could make `enum class Color {...}` to remove implicit conversion, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not hesitant to use the [boost library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/), then maybe you can do it using `boost::optional`.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

enum Color {
   red,
   blue
};

class example 
{
   boost::optional<Color> c;
   void set_color(Color c) { this->c = c; }
   Color get_color() { return c; }
   bool check_color_is_set()
   {
     if( c ){
       // color is set
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       // color is not set.
       return false;
     }
   }
}
```

The default value of `boost::optional<Color> c` will be `boost::none` by default. You can perform normal if-checks on it and see if something has been set it or not.

Here is the [documentation of Boost Optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) for your reference.

**NOTE :** I haven't used the STL version of optional but if you are not interested in using Boost, you can always use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as well.